# Meaning of these two points in sentence SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't know what meaning those two points?

```
select top 1 a.alllc as codigo, alunmff+' '+aluapat+' '+aluamat as nombre
from univv..dgmalu01 a
inner join univv..dgmalu05 b on a.alllc=b.alllc
where a.nlutipo='S' and b.alllc='" & uup & "'
and b.alupass COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CS_AS='" & cuup & "' "
```

Comment: This does not look like MySQL syntax (it looks like SQL Server). Please tag the database that you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like SQL Server.

SQL Server uses four part naming for database tables:

```
<server name>.<database name>.<schema name>.<table name>
```

Usually the server is omitted, so many people think of this as three-part naming.

In any case, the "schema" is often not important, particularly for people learning databases.  So, the habit is to have `..` stand for the default schema for the database.  In almost all cases, this is `dbo` -- unless someone has consciously changed it.

So `univv..dgmalu01` is probably shorthand for `univv.dbo.dgmalu01`.

Comment: I guess you answered your own question, he meant the two decimal points in a row.

Comment: I don't use SQL-Server, but I frequently see `[dbo].tablename`, so the database name is also often omitted.

Comment: then "univv" is the server name, do you know in which part (as default) of my code (asp.net) I can see the IP or something about "univv"?

Comment: @Kuroro . . . "Usually the server is omitted".  You have a three part name, so it starts with the database.

Answer (score 0):

When the schema name is omitted, either by using a 1-part name, or a 3-part name with `..` the object name is resolved based on the user's default schema, and if the object is not found in the user's default schema, it's resolved in the `dbo` schema.